# TYPO3 RealURL fileName configuration does not work with "type" parameter

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, realurl, typo3-4.5

I created in TYPO3 a new typeNum (based on unix timestamp) to render a dynamic javascript file. Now I want to include this dynamic javascript file using:

```
page.headerData.123 = TEXT
page.headerData.123{
    typolink.parameter = {$global.homePid}, 123
    typolink.returnLast = url
    wrap = <script type="text/javascript" src="|"></script>
}
```

And this works. But I have also installed the extension **RealURL** and want to get a nice looking path to this dynamic js file.

So I have added this, to realurl_conf.php:

```
'fileName' => array(
    'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 1,
    'index' => array(
        'mycool.js' => array(
            'keyValues' => array(
                'type' => 123
            )
         ),
    ),
),
```

This will be ignored.

-

### Workarround

If I add

```
typolink.additionalParams = &js=123
```

to typolink generation and

```
'keyValues' => array(
    'js' => 123
)
```

to RealURL configuration, it works.

Why is the predefined TYPO3 get parameter **type** not working?

Comment: I should mention, that this happens with version 1.12.7 of RealURL and TYPO3 4.5

Answer (score 2):

you should not set the typeNum via typolink.additionalParams but use typolink.parameter instead:

```
typolink.parameter = ID, TYPE
e.g.
typolink.parameter = {$global.homePid}, 123
```

or try something "dirty" like this:

```
NO additionalParams = &type=123
NO parameter = ID, TYPE 

but

wrap = ...script type="text/javascript" src="|&type=123">...
```

cheers!

t.

Comment: Adding type to parameter works for the `preVars` part in realURL conf, but the `fileName` part is still not working. Your second, dirty try will not work, cause realURL will ignore the type at all.